# Какое условие выдвинуть в for in , чтобы цикл прервался после нескольких итераций?

Tags: javascript

```
    let arr = {
    a: [1, 6, 9],
    b: [3, 1, 7, 3],
    c: [167, 137, 98]
};


const function = () => {
        let elem = document.querySelector('input').value;
        let out = document.querySelector('out');
        for (let key in arr) {
            if (arr[key].includes(Number(elem)) === true) {
                return out.innerHTML += '&nbsp;' + key;
            }
        }
        return out.innerHTML += '&nbsp;' + false;
    }
```

Доброго времени суток!Когда нету return ,соотвтественно цикл отрабатывает пока подходит условие ,но выводит еще и условие после цикла. Есть повторяющиеся значения в массиве , нужно чтобы выводил либо значения key (все ,которые подходят) , либо false,а если убрать return ,все работает ок , но выводит все значения key и в конце естественно false.Понимаю ,что все должно быть просто и логично ,но долго не могу вьехать как это сделать

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Что такое `a4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может что-то типа этого?

```js
const fn = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector("input").value;
  const out = document.querySelector(".out");
  let result = "";

  for (let key in arr) {
    if (arr[key].includes(Number(elem))) {
      result += key + "&nbsp;";
    }
  }
  out.innerHTML = result.length ? result : false;
};
```

Comment: Вы затираете старую разметку.

Comment: Спасибо ,очень помогли ! Чтобы не перезатирался результат ,можно выводить через text.content